# Getting to the Casablanca wineries from Valparaiso without a car

Tags: public-transport, alcohol, chile, valparaiso

I'm staying in Valparaiso and would love to visit some of the [Casablanca wineries](http://rutadelvinodecasablanca.cl/es/bodegas/) just down Ruta 68, however I don't have a car. Several sites, such as [this one](http://moon.com/2013/03/ruta-del-vino-de-casablanca-in-the-chilean-heartland/), mention that this is easy to do via public transit, but don't go into any more detail.

How can I get to Casablanca via public transit? Where are the pick-up and drop-off points, what sort of schedule do they run, and what are the prices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bus, Colectivo or Private Shuttle

[The Ruta del Vino website says you can get to the wineries via bus, colectivo or private shuttle, from Valparaiso.](http://rutadelvinodecasablanca.cl/es/localizacion/)

> ### TRANSPORTE
>
> Terminal de buses de Valparaíso:
>
>  Dirección: Pedro Montt 2860, Valparaíso.
>
> Colectivos Casablanca – Valparaíso y viceversa:
>
>  Dirección: Avenida Argentina con Pedro Montt, Valparaíso
>
> Servicios particulares contratados en la Ruta del Vino de Casablanca:
>
>  Contacto: kvaldes@rutadelvinodecasablanca.cl

#### Buses

[A quick search for bus departure times](https://www.voyhoy.com/search/index?lang=es&origen=valparaiso&origenpais=cl&destino=casablanca&destinopais=cl&fecha=23-03-2016&fechaReturn=23-03-2016) indicates that buses run daily every hour or so. The buses are operated by [Tur Bus](https://www.turbus.cl/). The journey takes approximately half an hour and the cost at the time of writing (March 2016) is 2700$:

[image: Tur Bus Valparaiso to Casablanca]

#### Colectivos and Shuttles

Colectivos and private shuttles must be arranged locally. Schedules and prices are therefore unavailable online. As a rough idea [Rome2Rio quotes 30-35 EUR for a taxi.](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Valpara%C3%ADso/Casablanca-Casablanca-Valparaiso-Chile)